# Voltage level in Britain's ERNIE

Tags: vacuum-tube

[image: ERNIE Schematic]

The attached image is from a schematic found for Britain's random number generator for Premium Bonds.  I think  that it's for the original equipment.

I'm trying to assess the feasibility of recreating part of ERNIE, but lack the necessary valve design experience.  Can anyone approximate the order of magnitude of voltage levels at the red dot, next to neon bulb V1?  I expect that it's low due to the decoupling capacitor C1, but I can't estimate the effect (if any) coming out of valve V2.  Not sure what all those grids and heaters do.  Am I looking at 200 volts or nearer 1 volt?

Comment: Isn't V1 a neon bulb ? Those usually light at 80 V and extinguish at 40 V, so there would be a triangular wave at the dot with 40 V negative-going spikes

Comment: @jp314 Can you please clarify?  Are these spikes present only during switch on and off, and not during normal operation?  I'd be wanting to connect the V1 stage output to modern logic and not blow it up!

Comment: They would be present continuously. If you connect an oscilloscope to the red dot, you should see them (if V1 is in fact a neon bulb).

Comment: @jp314 Thanks, but why would the neon be turning on and off?  It's subject to a constant 200VDC through the 33K and 10K resistances, so running at a steady 5mA.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The neon charges up to 80 V at a rate controlled by the 33k and 0.01 below it. When it reaches 80 V, it arcs over (and flashes) and discharges v. quickly down to ~ 40 V. This signal couples to the red dot via the 0.001, and so generates spikes across the 470k. Of course all this depends on whether or not V1 is actually a neon bulb, or a voltage stabilizer (I'm not familiar with them -- e.g. http://www.r-type.org/pdfs/7475.pdf )

Answer (score 1):

The grid with the red dot is similar to the gate in a JFET; the anode is like the drain, and the cathode is like the source. The other grids are there to optimise performance and would not appear in the operational equivalent circuit. Quiescent DC through the valve (and hence through the 1k) causes the cathode to be +ve wrt ground by a few volts, and this makes the grid -ve wrt the cathode (almost zero grid current flows through the 470k). This is the grid bias voltage. The quiescent voltage measured at the grid, relative to ground, will be zero.

Basically, the heater warms the cathode, which creates an electron cloud; the anode attracts the electrons; and the grid controls the flow of electrons from cathode to anode. Auxiliary grids are there to accelerate the electrons and to confine the electrons to the anode's neighbourhood once they've zipped thorough the grids.

Answer (score 1):

[CV4002 outline data here.](http://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_cv4002.html)

In short, 6.3V 0.3A heater, and non much else except it's also available with pins instead of wire ended, as CV4014 and very similar to [EF91](http://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_ef91.html) for which you should be able to find data.

The latter (EF91) page shows an example schematic with "Vg1=-2V" (for Va=250V) but note that Vg1 is measured relative to the cathode.

In Ernie, you will see that the cathode is self-biasing, like an N-JFET, with a 1 kilohm resistor. Now you'd need to plot load lines to be sure, but it's reasonable to guess the anode is at 100V (half the supply) making the cathode current 1mA and thus the cathode voltage is 1V above ground.

In this configuration the valve won't be drawing grid current, so the actual voltage measured at the grid - thanks to the 470 kilohm grid leak resistor is ... 0V. (Thus maintaining Vg1 = -1V relative to the cathode.)

Any other voltage than 0V on V2 grid indicates a fault : specifically, any positive voltage points at a leaky C1, and, by turning V2 on too hard, wastes power and potentially shortens its life (though at 2mA max Ic I wouldn't expect problems).

Comment: just to clarify, you suggest that the signal at the red dot would have been <1 volt P-P? Clearly the signal couldn't have been exactly 0 volts otherwise the circuit wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Sorry, no, that's the DC bias. The AC component would be whatever V1 provides, virtually no attenuation. If it's a neon, see jp314's comment. If it's something else, you'd need its datasheet, or test it with a scope.